# Securing WebAPI with Azure AD and Accessing it on Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, azure-active-directory

I’m trying (since 3 days, and more than 10 attempts) to get my Windows Phone (Xamarin iOS and Android afterwards) authenticated against Azure AD but somehow it is not working for me. I’m following article as mentioned here: http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/04/29/fun-with-windows-azure-ad-calling-rest-services-from-a-windows-phone-8-app/ 
I did following steps:

1. Created ASP.NET MVC5 web site with Org Account (app registers in my AD as AppA)
2. I added a Web API which returns Hello World string
3. I build the project and test if is working. I do get Hello World
4. Then I create Azure Web Site & download publishing profile
5. Publish existing ASP.NET MVC site with org account. VS asks for credentials and create another app in Azure AD (AppB)
6. The site and Web API works fine
7. I create Native app (AppC) in Azure AD and give access to Web API (from AppB)
8. I create Windows Phone application and provide return URL and client ID from (AppC)
9. I add resource URI for this native app from AppB
10. I type in code as it is from above URL.
11. Now, if I run the project, I do get below details:

> ```
> "access_token": "eyJ0eXAvv9w",
> "token_type": "Bearer",
> "expires_in": "3599",
> "expires_on": "1391805190",
> "resource": "https://mayurt.onmicrosoft.com/WebApp-dailystatusupdater.azurewebsites.net",
> "refresh_token": "AwAB...IgAA",
> "scope": "user_impersonation",
> "id_token": "eyJ0eXAIn0."
> ```

Now if I call the Web API, I’m redirected to login page but I can’t see any error. I tried Postman as well as Fiddler.

Comment: Have you also looked at http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/02/16/a-sample-windows-phone-8-app-getting-tokens-from-windows-azure-ad-and-adfs/?

Comment: You should post whatever you did that solved the problem and mark it as an answer, for the next person. :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Philippe Signoret.

And Thanks to Vittorio for his series of posts which helped me to solve this issue. You can find more information here: [cloudidentity blog](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/02/16/a-sample-windows-phone-8-app-getting-tokens-from-windows-azure-ad-and-adfs/)